# What is a principle behind designing const variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, constants

I'm wondering about the principle of `const` variable in javascript.

I know that const is mean constant variable. It means `const a = 1` and a will be unable to reassign a value. But, if I assign a object to `const` variable (`const a = { x: 1}`), i still can update value of fields inside the object, but cannot reassign the object. Because, assigning object to const is assigning reference of object to a variable, not a value inside them.

But, If I tell someone who doesn't know anything about coding that const is unable reassign variable. I think they may understand that `const a = { x: 1 }` and `a.x = 2` should be failed.

So, I'm wondering what is the abstract idea behind designing the `const` variable. Why in the first place, they think `const` be only apply on reference, not on value inside them too.

P.S. Sorry for my broken english grammar. I'm not native speaker.

Comment: you may want to read about `Object.freeze`, `Object.seal` and `Object.preventExtensions` properties

Comment: So you are expecting the object assigned to it should be immutable. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: `a.x` is not `a`, so `a.x = 2` is fine. Like you stated yourself, `const` is a type of variable, not an object property.

Comment: The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number one - there is nothing called "constant variables". The correct terminology is "constants".

The reason why the properties of the object you declared as a constant can be changed is that the object is referenced.

```
var i = 200;
const c = 300;
const o = {foo: "bar"}
```

Now, in the above example,

The symbol `i` is understandably a variable which has the value of 200.

The symbol `c` is a constant whose value is fixed to 300.

The symbol `o` is a constant which refers to an object. The value of `o` **is a memory address** which points to an object. What cannot be changed is this memory address, not what is in the address itself.

```js
const o = {foo: "bar"};


o.bar = "foo";   //The object properties, whats in the memory location the constant points to, can be changed
console.log(o);


try {
   o = {bar: "foo"}       
   console.log('I changed the value of a constant')
}
catch(e) {
    console.log('I cannot change the value of a constant. But whatever in the memory where the value is pointing to')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a misconception about `const`, in fact it doesn't creates immutable variables instead it creates immutable binding.

example:

```
 const myconst = YourObjectInstance;
 myonst  = AnotherInstanceOfObject // we will have an error here
```

in other hand:

```
 myconst.myProperty = 3 // will work fine because is a valid code
```

So `const` creates a binding to that particular object and assures that variable `myconst` won't have any other object's Binding.